# How to do something when AVQueuePlayer finishes the last playeritem

Tags: objective-c, ios, avqueueplayer

I've got an AVQueuePlayer which I'm creating from an array of 4 AVPlayerItems, and it all plays fine.

I want to do something when the last item in the queue finishes playing, I've looked a load of answers on here and this is the one that looks most promising for what I want:
[The best way to execute code AFTER a sound has finished playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604740/the-best-way-to-execute-code-after-a-sound-has-finished-playing)

In my button handler i have this code:

```
static const NSString *ItemStatusContext;

    [thePlayerItemA addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&ItemStatusContext];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:thePlayerItemA];

     theQueuePlayer = [AVQueuePlayer playerWithPlayerItem:thePlayerItemA]; 

    [theQueuePlayer play];
```

and then I have a function to handle playerItemDidReachEnd:

```
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
// Do stuff here
NSLog(@"IT REACHED THE END");
}
```

But when I run this I get an Internal Inconsistency Exception:

```
    An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: status
Observed object: <AVPlayerItem: 0x735a130, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x73559c0, URL = file://localhost/Users/mike/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.0/Applications/A0DBEC13-2DA6-4887-B29D-B43A78E173B8/Phonics%2001.app/yes.mp3>>
Change: {
    kind = 1;
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

This approach seems to work for me, within my button handler i've got a bunch of stuff to create URLs for the 4 mp3 files I want to play, then:

```
AVPlayerItem *thePlayerItemA = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:urlA];
AVPlayerItem *thePlayerItemB = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:urlB];
AVPlayerItem *thePlayerItemC = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:urlC];    
AVPlayerItem *thePlayerItemD = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:urlD];  

NSArray *theItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:thePlayerItemA, thePlayerItemB, thePlayerItemC, thePlayerItemD, nil];
theQueuePlayer = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:theItems];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[theItems lastObject]];
[theQueuePlayer play];
```

After which I have implement the 'playerItemDidReachEnd' selector like this:

```
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Do stuff here
    NSLog(@"IT REACHED THE END");
}
```

This queues up the 4 MP3 files and then when the last piece of audio has finished it calls the selector and my message appears in the console.

I hope that this is useful for someone else.

Answer (score 4):

Observing for status will not tell you when item is finished playing(it only tells when item is readyToPlay)

All you have to do it is to register for `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` **for the lastItem in your playbackQueue**, which use to initialise your `AVQueuePlayer` instance.

```
AVQueuePlayer* player = [AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:currentPlaybackQueue];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:currentPlaybackQueue.lastObject];
```

(note that selector has `playerItemDidReachEnd:`, you forgot two dots)

So then `-playerItemDidReachEnd:` will only be called exactly once in the end as you need it.
(also don't forget to remove yourself as an observer - you can do it in `-playerItemDidReachEnd:` using `notification.object`)

Have to say that there is **other way to do this**:
Using key-value observing for currentItem, then checking if the currentItem changed to `[NSNull null]` in `observeValueForKeyPath:`.

```
[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"currentItem"]) {

        if (change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] == [NSNull null]) {
            //last item finished playing - do something

        }
    }
}
```

normally for `AVQueuePlayer` you will register for `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` for each item in `playbackQueue`, so unless you don't want to store `playbackQueue` locally and check its lastObject with `notification.object` in `-playerItemDidReachEnd:`, you would use the second way

Answer (score 2):

You likely didn't implement the `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method in your class. Check out the [Apple KVO guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html) for further details.

Comment: I got it working using NSNotificationCenter rather than KVO, seems that the example that I blindly copied and pasted tried to use both approaches.

Comment: OK, yeah I was wondering why you were doing both. Hope this helped. Upvote and or accept would be appreciated :)